# Why dynamic radiobutton color is white?

Tags: android, radio-button, dynamic-ui

I read from a file a lot of data, and i a would like to create the ui from this. I create a lot of textview and a radiobutton, but when i try this on device or emulator i got white text everywhere, why?

If i create a radio button in the xml it is black! but my dynamic radio button color is white :(

```
public void buildScreen(){

    TextView header = new TextView(context);
    header.setText(dataManager.getHeaderString()+"\n"+dataManager.getqType());
    dataManager.setMainTable(tbl);

    TableRow row;
    for (Map.Entry<String, SimpleQuestionModel> entry : dataManager.getqDict().entrySet()){
        String question = entry.getKey();
        SimpleQuestionModel model = entry.getValue();

        row = new TableRow(context);
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(model.getQuestion());
        dataManager.getMainTable().addView(tv);

        RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(context);
        rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
        for (int j=0;j<model.getAnswers().size();j++){
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(context);
            rb.setText(model.getAnswers().get(j));

            rg.addView(rb);
        }
        dataManager.getqAndA().put(tv, rg);
        row.addView(rg);
        dataManager.getMainTable().addView(row);

    }

}
```

Here is my class constuctor:

```
public UIBuilder(Context context, TableLayout tbl) {
    this.context = context;
    this.tbl = tbl;
    dataManager = DataManager.getInstance();
    DataReader dataReader = new DataReader();
    dataReader.readDataFromFile("first.txt");
}
```

And i call this class like this:

```
 builder = new UIBuilder(getApplicationContext(), tbl);

    builder.buildScreen();
```

and tbl is a tablelayout in my xml

Comment: Please paste in the code where you are creating your "dynamic radio button".

Comment: You have a data member named `context`. How are you initializing it?

Comment: ohh f****ck... i know whats the problem... i used getApplicationContext() instead of "this"... -.-"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use the `Activity` as the `Context` when instantiating widgets, if you want your theme to be honored. Using any other `Context` will just use the stock system theme.

[This blog post](http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) by Dave Smith explains when to use what `Context`, including mentioning this problem.

Comment: More specifically, use the `Context` for the container in which the widget will be placed. For example, the Toolbar on API 21+ will often have a different theme (via a `ContextThemeWrapper`) from the rest of your activity. `AlertDialog` also has its own theme separate from the activity.